# Django ordenar una relación Many to Many de forma dinámica

Tags: python, django, api, djangorestframework, endpoint

Tengo un modelo con una relación many to many:

Modelo:

```
class AssignAudios(FieldDefaultsAbstracts):

disease = models.ForeignKey(Disease, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
audio = models.ManyToManyField(audios, blank=True)
order = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['order']

def __str__(self):
    return self.disease
```

Se que si no especificas, DJango te genera una tabla intermediaria donde se almacenara el id del registro con el id del audio relacionado, en este caso mi tabla intermediaria tiene el nombre por defecto -`assignAudio_assignaudios_audio`-, ahora mi pregunta es:

Si al relacionar me mandan `[3,6,1,7,2]`, al consultar ese registro la relacion Many to Many me traerá los datos en orden ascendente `[1,2,3,6,7]`, ¿Cómo puedo ordenar los ids de forma que coincidan con el orden que se especifico al inicio?

View:

```
class AsssignAudiosView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
model = models.AssignAudios
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )
serializer_class = serializers.AssignAudiosSerializers

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = self.model.objects.all()
    return self.filter(queryset)

def filter(self, queryset):
    kwargs = self.request.GET 
    disease = kwargs.get('disease', None)

    queryset = queryset.filter(
        is_active = True
    )
    if disease:
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            disease = disease
        )
    return queryset

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = serializers.CreateAssignedAudioSerializers(data = request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True)
    self.perform_create(serializer) 
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)

def perform_create(self, serializer):
    item = serializer.save(
        owner = self.request.user,
        is_active=True,       
    )
    return item

def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
    instance = self.get_object()
    serializer = serializers.CreateAssignedAudioSerializers(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_update(serializer)
    return Response(serializer.data)    

def perform_update(self, serializer):
    serializer.save(
        owner = self.request.user,
        is_active=True,  
    )

def perform_destroy(self, instance):
    instance.is_active = False
    instance.save()
```

Serializers:

```
class AudioSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = models.audios
    fields = ('id', 'name','audio','duration')
```

```
class AssignAudiosSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    audio = AudioSerializers(many = True)
```

```
class Meta:
    model = models.AssignAudios
    fields = ('id','disease','audio','order')
```

```
class CreateAssignedAudioSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.AssignAudios
        fields = ('id','disease','audio','order')
```

Estuve investigando y veo que mencionan el agregar un order a la tabla intermedia sin embargo ¿Cómo puedo agregar un campo a la tabla intermedia sin afectar los datos que ahí ya existen?
Vi que puedes usar `through`, pero solo funciona cuando tu defines la tabla intermediaria ¿Hay alguna alternativa mejor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí la solución a mi problema:

Primero:
Modifique mi modelo para usar una tabla intermediaria mediante [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/), agregando un campo order a la tabla intermediaria:

```
class AssignAudios(FieldDefaultsAbstracts):

disease = models.ForeignKey(Disease, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
audio = models.ManyToManyField(audios, blank=True, through='assignAudio_audio')
order = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)


class Meta:
    ordering = ['order']

def __str__(self):
    return self.disease

class AssignAudio_audio(models.Model):
assignaudios_id = models.ForeignKey(AssignAudios, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
audios_id = models.ForeignKey(audios, related_name="assigned_audios", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['order']

def __str__(self):
    return self.assignaudios_id
```

Luego en mi método POST/PUT agrego la lógica de ordenamiento:

```
audios_id = treatment_audios['audio']

for i in range(len(audios_id)):
assigned_audios = treatment_audio.objects.create(
    order = i+1,
    audio_id_id = int(audios_id[i]),
    treatment_id_id = treatment,
)
```

Que básicamente consiste en obtener el listado y agregarlo a la tabla intermedia asignándole un orden.

Al final la magia ocurre en el serializers:

```
class CreateTreatmentSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
audio = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

class Meta:
    model = models.treatment
    fields = ('id','users','name','order','audio','disease','days_of_treatment')

def get_audio(self, instance):
    audios = instance.audio.all().order_by('audios_treatment__order')
    return AudioSerializers(audios, many=True).data
```

Donde tomo la relación audios colocándole un **SerializerMethodField**
y finalmente agregado el método de abajo en el cual le digo que traiga los audio asignándole un order en base a la tabla intermediaria.

Referencia y solución aquí:
[Django Rest-Framework nested serializer order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48247490/django-rest-framework-nested-serializer-order)

Comment: Buena, solución y respuesta!